# sitecore multiple domains, shared items

Tags: sitecore

I have a site in sitecore at domain1.com

```xml
<site rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" .. />
```

I want to create a second site at domain2.com that uses same items

```xml
<site rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" ... />
```

Both sites refer to same items in content tree. Clear?

The links generated by `sc:path(.)` (makes absolute links) on the domain2.com refer to domain1.com.
As far as I understand links refer to the first site in web.config that refered to the items in content tree.

How can I get valid links for both sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `Rendering.SiteResolving` to `false`.
The the sitecore will determine the urls' hostname from http request.